# How to style display: flex elements to show as 3x2x3x2

Tags: html, css, flexbox, flex4, display

This is my code for a website on which I have boxes, which on click lead user to another page for specific article. I use `display: flex` to show them in a 3x3x3 rows, but I want it to be displayed in a 3x2x3x2 style, so that first row has a `width` of 33%, but in the second row each `box` has a width of around 50%. Is it achievable in any way? I can't find any suitable solution on the internet.
HTML:

```
<div class="boxes">

<div class="box">
 <a>
  <div class="photo">...</div>
  <div class="content">...</div>
 </a>
</div>

<div class="box">
 <a>
  <div class="photo">...</div>
  <div class="content">...</div>
 </a>
</div>

<div class="box">
 <a>
  <div class="photo">...</div>
  <div class="content">...</div>
 </a>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.boxes{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 column-gap: 20px;
 rów-gap: 20px;
}

.box{
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: calc(33.33%);
}
```

EDIT: of course I have more of these divs "box" but I just provided less to not make a mess

Comment: what is a 3x2x3x2 row? I wasnt aware of a 4th dimension

Comment: sorry if I explained it wrong, in the first row I want to have 3 boxes, in the second I want to have 2, then in the next one 3 again, then 2, then again 3 etc.

Comment: Look into using grid.

Comment: yes, probably a combination of grid a child selectors. Maybe try something like this: `.box:nth-child(5n),
.box:nth-child(5n + 3)`. Flex will probably not work for this, as the layout changes a lot depending on space available.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with a CSS Grid by creating a 6-column grid. Then you let all elements span 2 rows and select every 4th and 5th element of a group of 5 elements to span 3 columns.

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

section > div {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

section > div:nth-child(5n + 4),
section > div:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}

/* for visualisation purpsoe only */
div {
  min-height: 20vh;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</section>
```

You also can do this with Flexbox, however which will not allow the usage with gap without complicated calculations. Here you can also sue the `nth-child()` selector to select the 4th and 5th element of a group of 5 elements:

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section > div {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section > div:nth-child(5n + 4),
section > div:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  width: 50%;
}


/* for visualisation purpsoe only */

div {
  min-height: 20vh;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</section>
```

Comment: The formula for calculating the widths when using a gap with flexbox: multiply the gap size by the number of gaps in the row and divide by the number of divs in the row. Subtract this value from the width of the div. If `gap: 1em` then `div {width: calc(33.33% - .67em)}` and `div:nth-child(-) {width: calc(50% - .5em)` (minimized CSS for brevity)

Comment: @TimR While this is a very basic description it is not completely accurate and responsive. The solution is to use 2 CSS variables for the number of columns and the gap size. The formula is `width: calc(( 100% - (var(--columns) - 1)) * var(--gap)) / var(--columns))`. You should not try to round values within CSS. they open to pixel inaccuracies on larger screens.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I had thought about putting all of the calculations in the `calc()` but didn't think it was necessary. However, apparently it is necessary due to your report of pixel inaccuracies on larger screens. In this use case, the gap variable would be set (and used) in the `section` declaration block, and the columns variable would be set in both of the `section > div` declaration blocks. BTW, your formula has an extra `)` after `- 1`. Should be `width: calc((100% - (var(--columns) - 1) * var(--gap)) / var(--columns));`

Comment: @TimR that extra bracket has a purpose you need to subtract the gap space from the 100% first and then divide it by the numbers of columns. Otherwise the division would take place before the gap space is subtracted from the 100%. The first bracket is to close the `columns - 1` and the second to close the `100% - (columns -1)`

Comment: That gives an "invalid property value" error. I tested and verified that it works correctly after removing the `)` that I specified. That extra `)` would cause the number of columns to be subtracted from 100% and then multiplied by the gap.

Comment: my mistake you're right